# What is the difference between jackknifing and LOOCV?

Tags: cross-validation, resampling, method-comparison

[Leave-one-out cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#Leave-one-out_cross-validation) model technique is very similar to [jackknifing resampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackknife_resampling), because both omitting each training case and perform retraining of the network on the left-out subset.

On wiki page we can read that jackknifing computes a statistic from the kept samples only, while LOOCV computes a statistic on the left-out sample(s). However it is still not clear for me.

Can anybody elaborate on it, ideally with same practical examples?